# DoString is giving error while executing expression

Tags: c#, lua, lazy-evaluation

I am integrating Lua in my application. But I am getting error if I am adding any if condition in Expression

```
 string ifCondition =" return  10 + 1";
 string expression = "function f()\n" + ifCondition + " \nend";
 state.DoString(expression);
 var scriptFunc = state["ScriptFunc"] as LuaFunction;
 var res = scriptFunc.Call();
 Response.Write(res[0]);
```

If I run above code then it will work. now I am adding if condition then it will not work.

Here is my code

```
 string ifCondition ="If (10 < 2) then  \n return  10 + 1 \n else \n return 12 end";
 string expression = "function f()\n" + ifCondition + " \nend";
 state.DoString(expression);
 var scriptFunc = state["ScriptFunc"] as LuaFunction;
 var res = scriptFunc.Call();
 Response.Write(res[0]);
```

How can I execute if condition dynamically?

Comment: Not really an expert but i think lua is case sensitive so you can try to change "If (10 < 2) ..." with "if (10 < 2) ..."

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: thanks for your reply. you are right. Lua is case sensitive, and that's why only I am getting error. thanks for your time

Answer (score 3):

> string ifCondition ="If (10 < 2) then  \n return  10 + 1 \n else \n return 12 end";

Lua keywords are all lower case. Change the `If` to `if`.

By the way, C# supports multiline strings, so you could write the above as:

```
string ifCondition = @"
    if (10 < 2) then
        return  10 + 1
    else
        return 12
    end";
```

Not such a big deal here, but if your snippets get longer it'll get harder to maintain them as a single line.